# How to make HTML Button Link but no pop ups

Tags: html, button

I would like to create an HTML link button when it click, it will open a link but don't want to get it redirected to that link. I'm hoping that make sense because for example this code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.ca';">GOOGLE</button>
```

It will create a "GOOGLE" button and when it has been pressed, it will go the link "google.ca" in the same tab I believe. Basically what I want is to press this button, it will send the link, and still on the same page as I was before pressing the button. No new tabs or no new child window and I'm still in the same page as I was before clicking the button.

How can I do this?

P.S. please excuse my grammar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: send a link where? .. by email you mean?

Comment: So I think what he wants to say is that when you click the link, he wants a new tab to open up, but he doesn't want to be redirected to the tab with the link. Like clicking the middle mouse button or holding  `Ctrl` and left-clicking

Comment: not really sending my bad, its mostly just opening the link but dont want to have it physically opened if that make sense. I just want to stay on the same page when i click on the button.

Comment: basically i only want 1 webpage, which is my own html website, and i can keep pressing the button as much as i can that has a link on it. I know it sounds like im giving someone a virus but trust me im not.

Comment: You're saying you want to send an HTTP GET for a given URL? Like just a simple XHR / AJAX request?

Comment: this is for my iot project, where the link is the control to the arduino/esp8266 and when i press the button, itll control the arduino because the button opens the link. but when i do that i dont want it to actually redirected to the link because if i do, i will have to keep pressing backspace to my html website. thats the whole story

Comment: Yes, AJAX is what you're looking for.  It's a broad topic. just look it up.

Comment: @bryan60 getting the http for a given url basically yes what i wanted. but i dont know what is xhr/ajax request is

Comment: @bryan60 okay thanks for that. I will look into that hopefully that is what im looking for.

Comment: it's just a method for making HTTP requests in javascript. You can find endless resources by googling it.